# Is alternative in Unity like Ninject has: Global.Inject(this)

Tags: c#, ninject, unity-container

I use Unity and I have a class:

```
public class A
{
    [Dependency]
    IRepository<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have class B:

```
public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        /* In Ninject I would use */
        /* Global.Inject(this) */
        /* Is it possible to do in Unity? */
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate what `Global.Inject(this)` does? Is that a call that registers the current instance (which sounds more than useless) or is this something like a call to Unity's `container.BuildUp(this)` which only makes sense in a very limited set of use cases like in 'classic' ASP.NET webforms where you have no other way to use DI at all.

Comment: Global.Inject(this) is for initialize (in this example) User object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`container.BuildUp()` sounds similar to what you are trying to achieve. But I would strongly recommend not to use this feature inside a constructor unless you absolutely have to. ASP.NET webforms are about the only scenario where it makes sense from my point of view, as you have no way to control the instantiation of `Page` objects yourself and have to swallow what the framework decides to throw at you.

`BuildUp` should be reserved for "3rd party" objects served to you by external frameworks or applications (where again you don't have control over object instantiation) and you should never ever call the container inside your business or service objects directly (see the [ServiceLocator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)).

Comment: You also need the [Inject] attribute on the properties

Comment: @DanielMarbach In which case do you need the `InjectAttribute`?

Comment: For properties when you use Kernel.Inject